# Uncaught CRM Core_Exception Transaction/Manager.php

Tags: joomla, php

```
Joomla 3.4.3
CiviCRM 4.6.4
Apache/2.4.12 (Unix)
5.5.43-MariaDB
PHP 5.4.41
```

Attempt to quickedit existing entry and get "Network Error -- Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again."

Attempt standard edit and get "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment -- DB Error unknown error"

Web server error log shows: "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame\n\n  thrown in /var/www/htdocs/beast/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107"

No other errors show. Have tried purge cache, Firefox, Chrome, and IE. This problem did not exist with civicrm-4.5.6-joomla.

What should I look for?

Comment: Can you enable debug and backtrace in CiviCRM to get a more descriptive error?

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED: It was a mariadb error on mysql.proc. mysql_upgrade neither ran nor threw an error. Aftert mysql_upgrade, all seems well!