# Error when creating new contact: "Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception"

Tags: contacts, joomla

When I create a new contact I am getting a "Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception". Maybe this will happen when doing other things too, but I haven't run into them yet. This is quite problematic and prevents me from working with this CiviCRM installation, so I would really to have some help fixing this.

It is a clean install of CiviCRM version 4.6.10 on a clean Joomla! 3.4.8 install with PHP 5.5. No errors were given until I tried to create a contact. Re-installation of everything also didn't help at all.

*Full error message:*

```
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. 
DB Error: unknown error

Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: 
[0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in 
[...]/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php 
on line 107
```

Comment: Have you looked here? It sounds similar: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/uncaught-crm-core-exception-transaction-manager-php

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to recreate the error on the demo site: http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/

But the problem you are running into sounds the same as this issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16287

Perhaps there is some information there that will help?

Comment: Thanks for the respons, but I don't think that issue is related. At least the information in that ticket doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solved... sort of... almost...

Moving the database solved the problem, so the problem seems to be with the database server. How or why is not clear yet and I need to search for that some more, but at least this problem is solved.

If I find anything interesting I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in /var/www/example.org/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107

In our case there was a dedupe session running that was consuming a lot of mysql. Killing the query resulted (or coincided) with being able to add/edit without the error.