# submit button onclick

Tags: civicontribute

First time using civicontribute. We get a transaction error when submitting a donation. (see below)
Our donation form submit button has: onclick="return submitOnce(this,'Main','Processing');"

Other people with similar pages do not have an onclick function. 
Is that the cause of our problem?
Should we have it?
If not, how do we get the page to be rendered without it?

Here is the error message we get when clicking submit.

"Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: unknown error
Return to home page.

Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in .../wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107"

Comment: Can you check CiviCRM log to get detail error about DB Error: unknown error

Comment: where in the directory structure can I find the civicrm error log

Comment: <wordpressroot>/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigLog

Comment: Did you mean: <wordpressroot>/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved - after updated mariaDB
following
[Uncaught CRM Core_Exception Transaction/Manager.php](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/uncaught-crm-core-exception-transaction-manager-php)

and 
re-installed stripe.